# Cannot find symbol - method calcAverageBill(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>)

Tags: java

When I run my code I get this error, and I cannot figure out why.
The error is "Cannot find symbol - method calcAverageBill(java.util.ArrayList)"

The program is written in java.
First class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CO2Footprint
{
private int myNumPeople, myBulbsReplaced;
private boolean myPaper, myPlastic, myGlass, myCans;
private double myGalsUsed, myElectricBill, myElectricPrice, billSum,     priceSum;
/**
 * Constructor for objects of type CO2Footprint
 * @param galsUsed anuual gasoline used
 * @param electricBill average electricity bill
 * @param electricPrice average electricity price
 * @param numPeople number of people in home
 * @param paper whether or not paper is recycled
 * @param plastic whether or not plastic is recycled
 * @param glass whether or not glass is recycled
 * @param cans whether or not cans are recycled
 * @param bulbsReplaced number of light bulbs replaced
 */
CO2Footprint(double galsUsed, double electricBill, double electricPrice, int numPeople, 
boolean paper, boolean plastic, boolean glass, boolean cans, int bulbsReplaced) {
    myNumPeople = numPeople;
    myBulbsReplaced = bulbsReplaced;
    myPaper = paper;
    myPlastic = plastic;
    myGlass = glass;
    myCans = cans;
    myGalsUsed = galsUsed;
    myElectricBill = electricBill;
    myElectricPrice = electricPrice;
}
public double calcAverageBill(ArrayList<Double> myElectricBill) {
    for(int i = 0; i < myElectricBill.size(); i++) {
       billSum += myElectricBill.get(i);
    }// **** insert code for method here ****//
    return billSum/3.0;
}
public double calcAveragePrice (ArrayList<Double> myElectricPrice)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myElectricPrice.size(); i++) {
        priceSum += myElectricPrice.get(i);
    }// **** insert code for method here ****//
    return priceSum/3.0;
}
public double calcElectricityCO2 (double avgBill, double avgPrice)
{
    return (avgBill/avgPrice)*1.37*12;
    // **** insert code for method here ****//
}

}
```

Second class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class CO2FootPrintTester
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<CO2Footprint> CO2 = new ArrayList<CO2Footprint>();

    ArrayList<Double> myElectricBill = new ArrayList<Double>(3);
    ArrayList<Double> myElectricPrice = new ArrayList<Double>(3);

    myElectricBill.add(209.60);
    myElectricBill.add(249.68);
    myElectricBill.add(222.59);
    myElectricPrice.add(209.70/2464);
    myElectricPrice.add(249.68/2948);
    myElectricPrice.add(222.59/2621);

   double avgBill = CO2.calcAverageBill(myElectricBill);
   double avgPrice = CO2.calcAveragePrice(myElectricPrice);

   double emissions = CO2.calcElectricityCO2(avgBill, avgPrice);
   //***********************************************************

   System.out.println("|             Pounds of CO2             |       Pounds of CO2       |                |");
   System.out.println("|             Emmitted from             |       Reduced from        |                |  ");
   System.out.println("| Gas   |    Electricity    |  Waste    |   Recycling  |  New Bulbs |  CO2 Footprint |");
   System.out.println("|-------|-------------------|-----------|--------------|------------|----------------|");
   System.out.print(emissions);

   //***********************************************************

}
```

}

Comment: What is `CO2`? Does it have a `calcElectricityCO2` method?

Comment: NOTE: Everything in the constructor is needed, as the program is not finished yet.

Comment: `CO2` is just what I used to give it a name, it does not.

Comment: So why do you expect it to work?

Comment: A method processing a ` List<X>` need not be in class X. This is causing confusion.

Comment: @Redux so, if it doesn't have such a method, why are you trying to call it?

Comment: I thought it would call anything it found in the class.

Comment: @Redux And the problem is that `CO2` is of type `ArrayList`, and there is no method called `calcAverageBill` in the `ArrayList` class.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calcAverageBill` is a method defined in your `CO2Footprint` class, but you try to call it for an instance of `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<CO2Footprint> CO2 = new ArrayList<CO2Footprint>();
...
double avgBill = CO2.calcAverageBill(myElectricBill);
```

`ArrayList` doesn't have such method.

It's unclear what's the purpose of the CO2 ArrayList, since you never add any elements to it. Perhaps you should create an instance of `CO2Footprint` instead of the `ArrayList<CO2Footprint>`, and call `calcAverageBill` for that instance.

Comment: _It's unclear what's the purpose of the CO2 ArrayList, since you never add any elements to it. Perhaps you should create an instance of CO2Footprint instead of the ArrayList<CO2Footprint>, and call calcAverageBill for that instance._ I cannot as the constructor is a arraylist and it provides a mismatch argument error.